# How to install CentOS 4.7?

Tags: centos, system-installation

I am trying to install CentOS 4.7. When I get on to the mirror site, it offers me
different binaries, bin1of5, bin2of5,bin3of5, etc. I just want the basic version.
Which one should I download?

Thank you.

Comment: Which mirror site are you on?  Out of the handful of mirrors I tried many of them only have 4.8.  Is there a reason you have to use 4.7 or could you use a much more recent version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to the ISOs, you can download them using torrent:

- [CentOS 4.7 i386](http://vault.centos.org/4.7/isos/i386/CentOS-4.7-i386-binDVD.torrent)
- [CentOS 4.7 x86_64](http://vault.centos.org/4.7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-4.7-x86_64-binDVD.torrent)

You can always find older versions on http://vault.centos.org if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Download bin1of5, if it is like later releases, you can install a minimal system from that. You have to deselect **all** package-groups (including "Base") during the initial stage of installation. After booting the new system, you can install any required package-groups from the Internet repositories using `yum groupinstall package-group-name`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get away with the first three CDs/images. But agreed on the comments above about looking at a newer version. Support for the CentOS 4.x series ends in 2/2010.

`NOTICE: Support for CentOS 4 ends on Feb 29th, 2012`